# Restful routing feat Asp.net mvc 2 with multiple parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, rest, routes

Trying to solve next problem: 
I'm using RouteSet in my solution. My index page is mostly a grid, that accepts sorting and paging. So is there a way to specify pageNumber and sort option in url for eg:

somedomain/somecontroller/{page}/
somedomain/somecontroller/{page}/{column}/{order}/
somedomain/somecontroller/{page}/{column}/{order}/{id}

Area<SomeController>("some", () =>{Resources<SomeNestedController>();
                ....
            });
Thanks forward!

Answer (score 0):

create a model like:

```
public class KendoGridRequest
{
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string Logic { get; set; }

    public FilterObjectWrapper FilterObjectWrapper { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SortObject> SortObjects { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(KendoGridRequest request)
{
    ...
}
```

my route looks like:

```
map.Path("myroute/").To<MyController>(x => x.Index(null));
```

also if you are using kendo take a look at http://nuget.org/packages/KendoGridBinder/1.3